# Banner image doesn't cover the whole width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the banner image of my website responsive (cover the whole width), but when I resized the browser to lower than `~225px`, the image started to shrink.

The image is `6720x4480px`, so I don't think the size of the image is the problem here. I also tried other methods in SO but they didn't work or maybe I just couldn't find the right one. Note that the image did cover the whole width when I viewed it on mobile (e.g Mobile S-320px using Chrome), so in a way it was responsive, but I wanted to understand and solve this problem completely. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 2: Here's a GIF that I created for better visualization:

[gyazo.com/1658a06cb68eb6b37e6044d8e060b8c6](http://gyazo.com/1658a06cb68eb6b37e6044d8e060b8c6)

Edit: Thanks to @FluffyKitten's suggestion. After I reproduced the problem, I believe it may be because of the styling of the text, but still got no answer. What I was trying to do was similar to this example from W3Schools, where I could resize it just fine. 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background_hero

Here's the snippet:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  display: block;
}
/* Header */
header {
    position: relative; 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
header .hero-image {
    position: relative;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kNmmQcd.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
header .title {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
header .title .header-title {
    font-size: 8rem;
}
header .title .header-sub-title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    header .title {
      top: 45%;
    }
    header .title .header-title {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    header .title .header-sub-title {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>COFFEE TIME</title>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Header Section -->
 <header class="header" id="home">
    <section class="hero-image">
        <div class="title">
            <h1 class="header-title">Coffee Time</h1>
            <h2 class="header-sub-title">Enjoy our most delicious coffee</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that could cause this. Is this *all* the relevant code? Can you create a code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  (with Just the **relevant** code!) so we can see it in action? If we can't reproduce the error, we can't figure out whats wrong :)

Comment: Keep in mind, there is no device with `~225px` width or lower, so there is no need to optimize your picture for that particular case and this is a completely waste of time.

Comment: @SMAKSS That's true, but in my experience, its rarely a waste of time to fix a bug unless you know for a fact it will have no other adverse effects (which we don't here because we don't have all the details). And if nothing else, its definitely never a waste of time learning how to debug your own code :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks a lot. I have edited my post and added the snippet there.

Comment: The new code you posts works fine for me in Chrome & FF, no matter how small I make it. What are you testing it in when the image doesn't show properly?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I use VS Code and Live Server extension (by Ritwick Dey). After the Chrome browser is opened when you start the Live Server, Right-Click anywhere -> Inspect -> Toggle Device Toolbar. Then, resize the width of the browser. That's where I encountered the issue as mentioned above.

Comment: I wonder is it to do with how that is rendering the css then, because your code works fine in Chrome itself. Have you tested it yourself directly in the browser?

Comment: I believe I did. I have created a quick GIF for better visualization. 
https://gyazo.com/1658a06cb68eb6b37e6044d8e060b8c6

Comment: Your code seems OK to me. I would suggest using background-size: contain; once.

Comment: @Adesh Kumar Thanks I have tried that but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recreate the problem when the following 2 conditions are met:

- the device toolbar is turned on in Chrome inspector *and*
- the screen gets too narrow for the text to fit any more e.g. it can no longer
  fit the word "Coffee"

It's easier to see what's happening if you change the font some colour other than white. If I change "Coffee Time" to "Coffeeeeee Time", the white border on the right starts showing up around 580px *only when the device toolbar is on*. If I *don't* have the device toolbar on, I can resize the window to any size and it doesn't appear.

The good news is that this only happens when you are using the device toolbar in Chrome, but it's possible it could cause issues in other less popular browsers so it's no harm to address it.

To prevent this happening, you can add any of the following CSS rules to `header .title`:

- `overflow-wrap: break-word;` - this will force the word to wrap when it no longer fits on the screen
- `overflow:hidden;` - this will prevent the the part of the word that doesn't fit from appearing on the screen, thus preventing the "extra width" issue to kicking in.
- `overflow:scroll;` - lets the title text be scrolled.

Comment: Thank you, using the CSS overflow property solved the issue for me.